# What is the use of CertUI framework in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I want to delete CertUI framework from Xcode to fix an "bundle not loaded" issue. I want to know the use of CertUI framework in iOS programming so that i could know if it is needed to me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solid work! Delete first, then ask questions :)

Comment: @JustSid i guess thats kind of like your "Be sarcastic first, answer question later" :)

Comment: @logixologist I guess that's kind of like... Errr, let's not go down that rabbit hole.

Comment: @JustSid It is still in Trash!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is either [AppleOpenSource](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/security_certtool/security_certtool-55103/src/CertUI.h) or a 3rd party framework on GitHub. So someone added it, one can only wonder why?

The GitHub page does not have a ReadMe so it is hard to say what it does. neither does the Apple source.

Comment: There is also a private framework by that name, at least that's what a quick google search revealed.